# Umbraco Merchello: Programmatically retrieve product's collection

Tags: umbraco7

I have just started to use Merchello module on Umbraco 7.
How can I programmatically retrieve collection of a product?
Below is the code that I used to retrieve the particular product.

```
var mHelper = new MerchelloHelper();
var productContent = mHelper.TypedProductContent(productPropertyValue);
```

I couldn't find any method or properties of productContent that will return collection being assigned to this product.

===================================================================

Update: Rusty has replied my question on this in [Umbraco Forum](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/collaboration/merchello/merchello/76967-programmatically-retrieve-products-collection)

Comment: Have you tried downloading/installing the demo project? I'm thinking that you should be able to find an example somewhere in there.